# Geometric Progression of Air removed by an Air Pump

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If one third of the air in the tank is removed by each stroke of an air pump, what fractional part of the total air is removed in 6 strokes

Answer is 0.0877

I was thinking this was some sort of geometric progression

$${ \sum_{x=1}^6 (\frac {1}{3})^x }$$

But that doesn't work and I get 0.499314... Any Hint?

Comment: The answer is clearly not $0.0877$. Hint: Concentrate on the amount of air that *remains* after $1$ stroke, $2$, and so on. It will turn out that the answer they gave gives the amount of air *remaining*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking "one third of the air in the tank is removed by each stroke", think "two thirds of the air in the tank is left after each stroke."

Then after $0$ strokes there is $1$ of the air left.

After $1$ stroke there is $\frac 23$ of the air left.

After $2$ strokes there is $\frac 23\cdot\frac 23$ of the air left.

After $3$ strokes there is $\frac 23\cdot\frac 23\cdot\frac 23$ of the air left.

And so on.